# Using jsoup to extract specific cell of table

Tags: java, android, dom, jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup to extract specific cell of table. I have this code

```
Element vystraha = doc.select("#hzs-table > tbody > tr").get(oblast).select("td").get(1);
```

"oblast" is set to 0. So if I understand it correctly this should find table (element) with id "hzs-table" then move to its tbody then to first tr (or second if I set "oblast" to 1) and then select second cell of this row. However compiler shows indexOutOfBounds exception on get(oblast). Table that I am trying to extract is here http://www.hzs.sk/aktualne-informacie/podmienky-na-horach/

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the table is `hzs_table` (with **underscore** instead of minus!) try:

```
Element vystraha = doc.select("#hzs_table > tbody > tr").get(oblast).select("td").get(1);
```

Comment: yes thanks I saw it a minute ago ... my stupid mistake

Comment: no problem :) . Can I suggest a trick? You can use developer tools of Chrome or Firefox to find a tag in a html page, then right click and `Copy CSS Path`. This will give you the selector you can use in JSoup!